# Codeigniter AJAX JQuery csrf_protection star rating script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using the star rating script [here](http://www.codexworld.com/star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-php/) but I am using with Codeigniter with `CSRF_PROTECTION` turned on. I am receiving `500 Internal Server Error` when I click on the stars and the script is called. I found a few similar post here but none that helped me solve my issue.

I tried one fix which I found online that stated to create ajaxSetup (see below) function first to merge the "data" with the data in my function to send the token.

I do not know JavaScript so it is taking me days to figure out the issue. The ajaxSetup is not working. If I turn CRSF_PROTECTION off, the script works.

Help! Please, I am struck on this and want to get it to work because there are other Jquery scripts that I would like to use.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
data: { <?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_token_name'); ?>:
$.cookie('<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>') 
}
});
```

Here is all of the Java script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            data: {
            <?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_token_name'); ?>: $.cookie('<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>') 
            }
        });

            $(function() {
                $("#rating_star").codexworld_rating_widget({
                    starLength: '5',
                    initialValue: $('#rating_star').val(),
                    callbackFunctionName: 'processRating',
                    imageDirectory: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>i/icon',
                    inputAttr: 'postID'
                }); 
            });

            function processRating(val, attrVal){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>rating/rate',
                    data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        if (data.status == 'ok') {
                            $('#avgrat').text(data.average_rating);
                            $('#totalrat').text(data.rating_number);
                        }else{
                            alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked in the logs on your server, what the internal server error actually is? This is always a good idea, if there is an "internal server error" imho

Comment: do you really need csrf (on a POST no less) that simply hits a star counter?  is the avoidance of damage worth the effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set default value for data here

`$.ajaxSetup();`

and you are overriding  it here

```
 $.ajax();
```

so value of token not sending to your server, also you didn't send your data as JSON only you need to send it with with data

```
data:{"<?=$csrf['name'];?>":"<?=$csrf['hash'];?>"}
```

you need to send your data in json format

`data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,`

to

```
data:{"<?=$csrf['name'];?>":"<?=$csrf['hash'];?>", "postID":attrVal, "ratingPoints":val}
```

Comment: Wooo Hooo! That worked. Thanks! This is what I was trying to do. I tried this method before but but I kept receiving an error stating that I was missing a colon. The call was successful, the database was updated correctly and using Firebug I can see that the response is correct but the screen values did not update but I think I can figure that out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript that fires when the page initially loads, set up like this:

`$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '<?php echo $token; ?>' } });`

The `'X-CSRF-TOKEN'` might be different depending on if you changed that name etc.,